# How to get whats between two numbers in a string?

Tags: c#

I have a lot of movie files and I want to get their production year from their file names. as below:

Input: `Kingdom.of.Heaven.2005.720p.Dubbed.Film2media`

Output: `2005`

This code just splits **all** the numbers:

```cs
string[] result = Regex.Split(str, @"(\d+:)");
```

Comment: I think you could just do a `string.Split()` and pull it out of the array at the position. If the years is always in the same spot at least.

Comment: What do you expect as output for the movie: `The.Exterminators.of.the.Year.3000.1983.720p.dubbed.Filem2media` ? (see: [*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0085514/?ref_=ttls_li_tt)), But there are more movies with [a year in the title](https://www.imdb.com/list/ls086468030/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be more specific about which numbers you want. E.g.

Regex to find the year (not for splitting):

```
\b(19\d\d)|(20\d\d)\b
```

- `19\d\d` selects numbers like 1948, 1989.
- `20\d\d` selects numbers like 2001, 2022.
- `\b` specifies the word limits. It excludes numbers or words with 5 or more digits.
- `|` means **or**

But it is difficult to make a fool proof algorithm without knowing how exactly the filename is constructed. E.g. the movie "2001: A Space Odyssey" was released in 1968. So, `2001` is not a correct result here.

To omit the movie name, you could search backwards like this:

```cs
string productionYear =
    Regex.Match(str, @"\b(19\d\d)|(20\d\d)\b", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

If instead of `720p` we had a resolution of `2048p` for instance, this would not be a problem, because the 2nd `\b` requires the number to be at the word end.

---

If the production year was always the 4th item from the right, then a better way to get this year would be:

```cs
string[] parts = str.Split('.');
string productionYear = parts[^4]; // C# 8.0+, .NET Core
// or
string productionYear = parts[parts.Length - 4]; // C# < 8 or .NET Framework
```

---

Note that the regex expression you specify in [Regex.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split) designates the **separators**, not the returned values.

Comment: What about `2001.a.space.odessy.1968.720p.Dubbed.Film2media`?

Comment: Yes, I addressed this question. Search right to left.

Answer (score 2):

I would not try to split the string, more like match a field. Also, consider matching \d{4} and not \d+ if you want to be sure to get years and not other fields like resolution in your example

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```cs
string str = "Kingdom.of.Heaven.2005.720p.Dubbed.Film2media";
string year = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\.)(\d{4})(?=\.)").Groups[1].Value;

Console.WriteLine("Year: " + year);
```

Output: `Year: 2005`

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KM2PNk

- `\d{4}`: This matches any sequence of four digits.
- `(?<=\.)`: This is a positive lookbehind assertion, which means that the preceding pattern must be present, but is not included in the match. In this case, the preceding pattern is a dot, so the regular expression will only match a sequence of four digits if it is preceded by a dot.
- `(?=\.)`: This is a positive lookahead assertion, which means that the following pattern must be present, but is not included in the match. In this case, the following pattern is a dot, so the regular expression will only match a sequence of four digits if it is followed by a dot.

Comment: Thanks. fixed. My code :

var regex = new Regex(@"(\b(19\d\d)|(20\d\d)\b)");
                var myInput = txtMovieNameMain.Text;
                foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(myInput))
                {
                    txtMovieYear.Text = m.Value;
                }